# Copy tables form schema in another schema in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a procedure or a cursor.
Input data  -- NAME OWNER.
We know name  (OWNER) AND from table  ALL_OBJECTS 
Take the name of the table.
Tables > 30.
How to write correctly ?

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USER_NAME
(

  v_USER VARCHAR2 
)
AS 
  v_sysdate VARCHAR2(10) := to_char(SYSDATE ,'MMDDYYYY');
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(50);  

BEGIN

  SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME INTO v_table_name 
  FROM 
    ALL_OBJECTS F   -- Table with two columnsю. OWNER AND NAME TABLES 
  WHERE
    F.OWNER  = v_USER;

   --Name of tables and owner ALL_OBJECTS 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE USER_BANCU.'||v_USER||'_'||v_table_name||'__'||v_sysdate||to_char(sysdate,'HH24_MI_SS')||'    AS  
             SELECT *
             FROM '||v_USER||'.'||v_table_nam;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: I think that we need a loop.

Comment: Нужен цикл  что бы взять имнеа таблиц.

Comment: Need a cycle that would take imnea tables.

Comment: Just 30 tables, I can do that in couple of seconds using a good text editor. No need of PL/SQL loop etc. *No need to reinvent the wheel*. I would suggest, have a look at **DBMS_METADATA_GET_DDL** procedure.

Comment: What you are doing in the execute immediate statement, you could do the same in pure SQL to create the DDL, then save it as a sql file and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Try DBMS_METADATA_GET_DDL.

[enter link description here](https://www.google.md/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEzaO8hObLAhUG2ywKHcozA3MQFgglMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcd%2FB28359_01%2Fappdev.111%2Fb28419%2Fd_metada.htm&usg=AFQjCNH2osHCQBjiPBM-XXfb0idFKZZM2Q&sig2=5EwwyAQimDOPMKPIZE8Lkw&bvm=bv.117868183,d.bGg)